# Java Script mapping objects method to a object in an array?

Tags: javascript, oop, functional-programming

I know how to apply a method whole array with `myArray.map( fn )`.

Although it looks weird and awkward, I want to run each objects method taking parameter as it self. Like

```
function MyObject(i) {
 this.i = i;
 this.internalMethod = function () {
     return this.i * 100
   }
}

function externalMethod(object){
   return object.i * 100
}

var objects = [new MyObject(3), new MyObject(-1), new MyObject(5)]
objects.map ( externalMethod ) // This works but
/// [300, -100, 500]

objects.map ( arrayElements.internalMethod )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the internal function in an anonymous function and pass it the currently mapped object.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/qz6tpna4/1/)

```
var newObj = objects.map(function(curr) {
    return curr.internalMethod()
});
console.log(newObj)
// [300, -100, 500]
```